# Magento 2.3 : EE - Segments for visitor only return empty

Tags: magento2.3, magento2-enterprise, magento-2-commerce

In Magento 2.3 EE, we have few segments which is applicable for both visitors and registered customers also but it is not returning segment id for guest user **i.e., visitors**

> NOTE : It was working well and fine in M2.1x

See the below code to get more info about it

```
Magento\CustomerSegment\Model\Customer $customerSegment,
```

in **execute()**

```
$this->customerSegment->getCurrentCustomerSegmentIds();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'd take a look at the SQL that's used. It's hard to help you with the information oyu provided

Comment: What else you need apart from this, it was returning the segment id for guest user in  M2.1 X

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide you a magic fix for this. you will hvae to debugg it and see what's causing the issue

Comment: @PhilippSander Magento 2.3 have changed to init  to set segments for customer session. so if you know that the thing is been changed in M2.3 let me know the information about it. so I could work on it